# I need advice in handling or nor handling carbon copys

Tags: discussion

After getting 2 Flags not handled, I flagged them with other as "plagiarism of @sihrc 's content"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25745508
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25745428
which seems apparently not have been correct, I started investigation here on Meta an found that leaving a comment, maybe downvoting seems to be the appropriate way to handle cases like this.

Another flagging as "not an answer" since is was "On which line is this?" and copy of an old answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25891394
got disputed, I decided to brake with the flagging.

In the review now I stumbled over 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920767
 (I do not think it was coincidence)  and decided to ask for advice how to handle these situations.

My instinct would be to flag it as NAA since it seems to be a comment on David-Star's answer and would love to handle https://stackoverflow.com/a/17322673 another copy of this answer too, but I feel really insecure about my judging ability.

Comment: Just as an FYI, we have about 2k flags in the queue.  It takes a bit of time for us to process "Other" flags.

Comment: @bluefeet thank you for the information, it was not a ranting, just the feeling something might be wrong with my flagging.

Comment: I'd only question your flagging if they were declined, since they haven't been reviewed yet, it's hard to say. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first two, I decided to delete them both, since they don't seem to be adding any value (without diffing them against the original code, it's hard to know where he even changed it).  It doesn't seem like plagiarism; it seems like an effort at code-correction.

I deleted the second one.  It looks like a question to me.

The third one is in a foreign language (already been deleted).  You can custom flag those as "Not in English".

The last one: already deleted.

Comment: Thank you, but my desire was to learn how to deal with it, from what I've found so far downvoting and leaving comments would be the  appropriate way ? A carbon copy flag does not exist and Other seems to be very burdensome for administrators.

Comment: If it was an exact copy of the code, I apologize (I didn't check).  It seemed more like the user was trying to use answers as a poor man's Git.